# Htaccess rewrite (Cond and) Rule to rewrite these

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been struggling with this as I'm not so good in rewriting.

I want a URLs like these:

```
http://www.example.com/d/page1
http://www.example.com/d/page2
http://www.example.com/d/anythinghere
```

to always resolve (rewrite) to this:

```
http://www.example.com/dir.php
```

or maybe event better to:

```
http://www.example.com/dir
```

which in turn should be rewritten to `/dir.php`

For those who would like to know why is this needed:
I need to have my AngularJS non-single-page-app work without hashbangs where I need my pagination or anything - I want to have distinctive page URLs in order for the Web spiders to crawl my content properly.

So I'm hoping that I will be able, by making such requests resolve always in my page where AngularJS is `dir.php` to have links: `<a href="/page3" ng-click="someMethod()">Go to page 3</a>`

I'm still not sure if this is going to work at all. Anyway, the purpose of this rewrite thing is to force the server not to go away from this page when such a link is clicked. This just struck me: but it would create at least a page reload, wouldn't it? If so, that's really bad...

Comment: You want to rewrite every page to `dir.php` or `dir`

Comment: Something like that, yes

Comment: Ok if i understand your question, assume if i click the above link `/page3` the application logic will surf the `page3` in `dir.php`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/d/(.*)$ dir.php/$1
RewriteRule ^/dir/(.*)$ dir.php/$1
```

First rule will change everything afer /d/ to /dir.php

Second rule will forward everything after /dir/ to /dir.php

Comment: Your suggestion assumes actual existence of /dir subdirectory. But this is not the case - my dir.php should be in the root (it's a file)

Comment: Changed it, all forwards now to /dir.php

Comment: Actually I was trying myself the same (or very similar to this) before posting here. It didnt work (i'm referring to the line 1)
If I remove leading slash, it will work but css is broken, that is `d` is put into the base URL

Comment: Did you put this before it: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` ? This checks if the request is a file or directory...

Answer (score 0):

on your menu change the link

```
<a href="dir.php">Your Menu <a/>
```

to

```
<a href="dir">Your Menu <a/>
```

in the. htaccess file try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir dir.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all my previous attempts were valid - the thing is I was getting broken layout so I assumed rewrites weren't completely correct. It turned out including `<base href="/">` rectified the thing by forcing the paths to be relative to the root.